# Where I put the sql statement to store in database for blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sql, ajax

I'm using [Blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) for multiple image uploads, Where I put the sql statement to store **image file name** in database for blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload ?

Comment: You can put it in your PHP file. Anything else you would like to ask?

Comment: which php file and what is the syntax for it?

Comment: The PHP file that you have configured to recieve the file upload. As far as the syntax is concerned what have you tried? I hope you don't expect us writing the code for you without showing some efforts on your side.

Comment: Blueimp is very popular but its documentation (as well as a good part of Github's) is very poor indeed (or I'm not looking in the right place). I should have a blueimp with DB query on my other comp.

Comment: $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
  if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("zeeshan", $con);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO zeeshan.scroll_images (scroll_images.name, scroll_images.order) VALUES ('$file_name', 0)");

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Can you see my related problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502449/blueimp-jquery-file-upload-integrated-with-database/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside your blueimp_root > server > php folder, open the `upload.class.php` and add your code inside the `public function post()` right before the `header('Vary: Accept');`:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("zeeshan", $con);
for($i=0; $i<count($info); $i++) {
    if (!isset($info[$i]->error)) {
        $filename = $info[$i]->name;
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO zeeshan.scroll_images (scroll_images.name, scroll_images.order) VALUES ('$file_name', 0)");
    }
}
```

This will iterate through all uploads checking if they were successful and inserting their filenames into the database.

You may use `$info[$i]->url` to get the uploaded file's `url` as well.

Here's the full code with my original query if you need more reference: http://codepaste.net/p84dao

Comment: i'm getting: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: @zeeshanansari Oh sorry I was away for a while. Was the error in my code? If so you can edit my answer to fix it. `:)` Glad it worked.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté How about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502449/blueimp-jquery-file-upload-integrated-with-database/

Answer (score 0):

go to server/php/upload.class.php line: 313, add a new line and write:

```
$file_path = $this->options['upload_dir'].$file_name;
```

and echo this, it is the path of uploaded file, if it is true, write you sql query there.

Comment: but i only want to insert image(upload) name into database  not full path of image

Comment: you mean: `$file_name= $this->options['upload_dir'].$file_name;`

Comment: no $file_name is exists there, you must write you sql insert code there
add this code:
line 314: $query = "INSERT INTO images VALUES ('$file_name')";
line 315: mysql_query($query);