# Blueimp jQuery File Upload Integrated with Database

Tags: php, jquery, database, file-upload, blueimp

This plugin reads image files on **blueimproot/server/php/files** on page load. I need to read records from database, and replace 'download' HTML structure with my custom structure. I want to show catalog products, which items are affected by uploading/removing images through this plugin.

I've done this so far:

- I changed `public function get() { ... }` in **blueimproot/server/php/upload.class.php** to retrieve records from database. This function returns json object.

  ```
  public function get() {
      /* default code of Blueimp
      $file_name = isset($_REQUEST['file']) ?
      basename(stripslashes($_REQUEST['file'])) : null;
      if ($file_name) {
          $info = $this->get_file_object($file_name);
      } else {
          $info = $this->get_file_objects();
      }

      header('Content-type: application/json');
      echo json_encode($info);
      */

      include_once('../../../../connection.php');

      $id_cat = $_REQUEST['catid'];
      $query = "SELECT id, name, price, img_path FROM products WHERE id_cat = $id_cat ORDER BY id";
      $prods = mysql_query($query);

      $prod_arr = array();
      while($prod = mysql_fetch_assoc($prods)) {
          $prod_arr[] = $prod;
      }

      header('Content-type: application/json');
      echo json_encode($info);
      }
  ```
- I found that function is called from *index.php* in **blueimproot/server/php**:

  ```
  switch ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
      ...
      case 'GET':
          $upload_handler->get();
          break;
      ...
  ```

  }

I don't know where the returned json object is processed to show to UI. Have been 2 days and still can't track that function flow. Please help. Thanks.

Original Online Demo:
http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

Original Plugin Download:
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/downloads

Comment: So you want to list/filter only files uploaded by a certain user? If you show what you've edited and/or link to the full code or provide a sample of the JSON object which you're echoing it'd help a lot.

Comment: No, I'm trying to retrieve products from database, each product has image path. Adding/Removing image files through this plugin must affect database and UI. I updated the thread.

Comment: I see. What's your expected result? You want to upload and retrieve multiple images for each product? Or limit it to one image which is saved in the `img_path`? And what's your main difficult? Displaying the product image in the product page?

Comment: Oh, looking at your function again, I see that you're echoing a JSON already. I'll debug it a little to check if it's in the right format.

Comment: I hope something like Facebook does, upload multiple files and insert those to the same album (category in my case). I'll host it for you shortly.

Comment: I'm trying some bits of code to filter it but blueimp just isn't going my way. Here's a [ticket on DB support](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/957) for blueimp, which just covers how to insert the data in the DB -- very similarly to my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11181002/1331430) which you commented on. I'm willing to help, but keep in mind that blueimp was not designed for db support primarily (only god knows why they make such a great file uploader without any focus in DB support though).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401756/how-to-integrate-blue-imp-file-upload-to-cakephp/11407169#11407169. Hope this link will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 public function get() {
    /*
    $file_name = isset($_REQUEST['file']) ?
        basename(stripslashes($_REQUEST['file'])) : null;
    if ($file_name) {
        $info = $this->get_file_object($file_name);
    } else {
        $info = $this->get_file_objects();
    }
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($info);
    */
        $id_cat = $_REQUEST['catid'];
        $query = "SELECT id, name, price, img_path FROM products WHERE id_cat = $id_cat ORDER BY id";
        $prods = mysql_query($query);

        $prod_arr = array();
        while($prod = mysql_fetch_assoc($prods)) {
            //$prod_arr[] = $prod;

            $file = new stdClass();
            $file->name = "";// here image name goes i do not find image name in your select query
            $file->size = filesize($prod["img_path"]);// should be complete path
            $file->url =  $prod["img_path"];// should be relative path (http://localhost/images/234.jpg)
            $file->thumbnail_url = $prod["img_path"]; // thumbnail path
            $this->delete_type = "DELETE";
            $this->delete_url = ""; //here delete url you can delete image from database 
            array_push($prod_arr,$file);
        }
        header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($prod_arr);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is to open up the [Network Tab in Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/network) and watch for any GET requests to `server/php/index.php`. If it happens after a specific event then you'll have a better idea of where you should look.

I did look through the source files and the only GET request I found was in [main.js](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/main.js#L67-75)

```
$('#fileupload').each(function () {
  var that = this;
  $.getJSON(this.action, function (result) {
    if (result && result.length) {
      $(that).fileupload('option', 'done')
        .call(that, null, {result: result});
        }
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Following this WIKI:  https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Working-with-databases

I setup uploads to be inserted into a database,  then i changed my GET function as follows:

```
            public function get() {
                $uploads = $this->query_db();
                header('Content-type: application/json');
                echo json_encode($uploads);
            }
```

and my query_db function as follows:

```
         public function query_db() {
    $uploads_array = array();
    $select_result = $this->query("SELECT * FROM `uploads` ORDER BY `file_name`") or die(mysql_error());
    while($query_results = mysql_fetch_object($select_result))
        {   
            $file = new stdClass();
            $file->id = $query_results->id;
            $file->name = $query_results->file_name;
            $file->size = $query_results->file_size;
            $file->type = $query_results->file_type;
            $file->url = "http://files.domain.com/".$query_results->file_name;
            $file->thumbnail_url = "http://thumbnails.domain.com/".$query_results->file_name;
            $file->delete_url = "";
            $file->delete_type = "DELETE";
            array_push($uploads_array,$file);
        }
    return $uploads_array;
}
```